# exit status from rsync command

Tags: rsync, exit-status

When I am executing `rysnc` command the exit status is 0, even though the command throws an error (code 23). I want to use the exit status code to terminate the script when there are no files found but I am not able to do so, as it gives exit status 0 only. Is there any other method so that I can terminate my script when files not found?

```
$ rsync -a --files-from=test.txt . tmp || true
  rsync: link_stat "/home/user/a.txt" failed: No such file or directory (2)
  rsync: link_stat "/home/user/b.txt" failed: No such file or directory (2)
  rsync: link_stat "/home/user/c.txt" failed: No such file or directory (2)
  rsync: link_stat "/home/user/d.txt" failed: No such file or directory (2)
  rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]
$ echo $?
  0
```

Comment: Apart from forcing an exit status of zero with `true`, would you want to distinguish between _no_ files found and _some_ files not found?

Comment: I would just want to know "no files"  found as files found list would be very huge..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Roops23, the problem is `|| true`. Since `any_code` OR `true` will always give you 0.

So the command

```
$ rsync -a --files-from=test.txt . tmp
```

gives the exit code as you want (namely 23)!!!

Comment: Note that this would give you an exit code of 23 if _any_ file was not found. The user, in the question as well as in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/512714/exit-status-from-rsync-command?noredirect=1#comment948225_512714), wants to detect when _no_ files were found.